# How to get the index of a NSArray in its parent NSMutableArray after its been fetched by a predicate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am filtering a `NSMutableArray` to fetch an object(`NSDictionary`), Then I want to get this object's index in the original `NSMutableArray`. But somehow the index given is `2147483647` when there are only 5 items in that array.

Could anyone point how could i get the index of the fetched object in its original array?

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"data.resourceID == %@",addEvents[@"resourceID"]];
                result = [appDataMutable filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
                NSLog(@"%i",[appDataMutable indexOfObject:result]);
//...
 [appDataMutable replaceObjectAtIndex:[appDataMutable indexOfObject:result] withObject:resultDictionary]'
```

Comment: -1 for not reading the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an object is not found in an array, [`indexOfObject:` returns `NSNotFound`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject%3a), defined as

```
enum {NSNotFound = NSIntegerMax};
```

`NSIntegerMax` is `0x7fffffff`, i.e. 2147483647.

Comment: How can it be not found when I've just fetched the object? What am i missing?

Comment: `result` is an array. You'll probably need to check that its length is > 0 and then get the actual result at `result[0]` or `result.lastObject`.

Comment: I was just going to reply. I tried result[0] and it worked! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> result = [appDataMutable filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
> NSLog(@"%i",[appDataMutable indexOfObject:result]);
> ```

`filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` does not return some single object from the starting array; it returns another array, containing zero or more of the objects in the original array (namely, the ones that match the predicate).

That array contains some (or none) of the objects in the original array; it does not get added to the original array, nor was it ever there before, so it is not one of the objects in the original array.

As such, asking the original array for its `indexOfObject:` the filtered-down array will get you a result of `NSNotFound`, which is what you saw.

The solution, as Kevin mentioned in a comment on his answer, is to check whether the result array is empty or not (check its `count`) and then use the object(s) in that array.

### A postscript

If you expect there to only be one object in the result array, you should probably assert that condition, which will raise an exception if that isn't the case. (Your choice whether you want to assert that the array's count is *exactly* one or *less than or equal to* one.)

If you want to handle the case of more than one match, you should probably use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` instead, evaluating the predicate yourself for each match.